# How to keep all public members except one during proguard obfuscation?

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

Source example:

```
// this is package visible interface
interface MyInterface {
    void foo();
}

public class MyClass1 implements MyInterface {
    // some public class members which should not be obfuscated
    // ...     

    // this is MyInterface implementation, this method should be obfuscated:
    void foo() {}
}

// other classes which implement MyInterface
...
```

How do I keep all public members in MyClass1 and in other classes while only obfuscating MyInterface.foo() implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGuard doesn't provide any shortcuts to specify all methods but one. You'll have to specify the ones you need. Presumably, there is a reason why you have to keep them. For instance, if they implement another interface, you can easily specify to keep all the methods of this other interface.

Note that -keep specifications refer to the names of the classes/fields/methods, not to the code of the methods:

ProGuard manual > Usage > [Overview of -keep options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoverview)

Answer (score 2):

Considering that it's only one method you want to obfuscate, why don't you just rename your `void foo()` method to something like  `void y()` (or some random letter you like)?

If you really can't deal with remembering one strange-named method while debugging, you'll have to `-keep` all the other methods individually.

Another option is to extract the method to another class, or make a subclass, but that's probably not what you wanted.